# Clarification on python websockets example

Tags: python, function, websocket

From the example found here: http://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html

Can someone explain what the parameter 'path' does here? Is it a tuple for the host and port needed by websocket.serve()?

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def hello(websocket, path):
    name = await websocket.recv()
    print("< {}".format(name))

    greeting = "Hello {}!".format(name)
    await websocket.send(greeting)
    print("> {}".format(greeting))

start_server = websockets.serve(hello, 'localhost', 8765)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation for `websockets.serve`](http://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#websockets.server.serve) says that its first argument is `ws_handler`:

> ws_handler is the WebSocket handler. It must be a coroutine accepting two arguments: a WebSocketServerProtocol and the request URI.

In function `hello`, the second argument is not used, but it must accept the argument, because the argument is going to be sent to it by `websockets.serve`.

Comment: It just wasn't clear what type of variable path was. Is it a tuple? Or perhaps I just haven't had much experience with frameworks that require called functions to have variables in their signature that the function doesn't actually use.

Comment: The document says that it is an URI, so I guess it is either just one string, or a [`WebSocketURI` object](http://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/websockets/uri.html?highlight=WebSocketURI), which is a named tuple. It would be best to print it and see what comes out ;)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I'd upvote your answer but I don't have the rep.